# Bluetooth можно ли написать своё приложение к фитнес браслету?

Tags: bluetooth

Знакомлюсь с технологией Bluetooth и интересует возможно ли написать своё приложение(Android) к существующему устройству(например фитнес браслет), если при этом мы не знаем в каком виде передает данные браслет?
Если возможно, то какие подводные камни стоит ожидать?

В рамках дипломного проекта мой руководитель хочет взять готовый такой браслет и хочет, чтобы я написал для него приложение, в котором буду получать данные с браслета и потом их как-то обрабатывать

Comment: Можно, без особых проблем. Основная (и единственная) проблема - определить как и что передает браслет. Если это нечто стандартное, то все просто. Если не стандартное, то берем любое приложение (хоть это www.btframework.com/GattClient.zip) и смотрим, какие сервисы и характеристики есть у браслета. Далее смотрим, что можно прочитать. Ну и потом соотносим данные с заведомо известным поведением (скажем, счетчиком шагов).

Comment: Вроде бы самое крупное из подобных приложений с открытым кодом -- [GadgetBridge](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge). Если он ещё не поддерживает этот браслет, есть смысл вместо написания очередного UI-велосипеда оказать миру услугу и добавить его поддержку туда, [там только рады будут](https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/wiki/Support-for-a-new-Device). Уже разбор проприетарного протокола наверняка окажется весёлым приключением.

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что для большинства популярных фитнес браслетов протоколы уже кем-то проанализированы и исходники для работы с ними выложены на github. Однако, если выбрать какую-то экзотику, или что-то совсем уж свежее, то скорее всего придётся анализировать программы компании-производителя. Не уверен, что просто читая ячейки можно полностью разобраться где что и как.
Upd про подводные камни, вероятность этого небольшая, но надо быть готовым к тому, что: у одной и той же модели разные версии железа или прошивок могут работать по-разному; у конкретной пары устройств могут быть какие-то проблемы со взаимодействием через Bluetooth.